# Reading URL socket backwards in Python

Tags: python, sockets, memory

I'm attempting to pull information from a log file posted online and read through the output. The only information i really need is posted at the end of the file. These files are pretty big and storing the entire socket output to a variable and reading through it is consuming alot of internal memory. is there a was to read the socket from bottom to top?

What I currently have:

```
socket = urllib.urlopen(urlString)
OUTPUT = socket.read()
socket.close()
OUTPUT = OUTPUT.split("\n")
for line in OUTPUT:
    if "xxxx" in line:
        print line
```

I am using Python 2.7. I pretty much want to read about 30 lines from the very end of the output of Socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want in this use case is the `HTTP Range` request. Here is tutorial I located:

http://stuff-things.net/2015/05/13/web-scale-http-tail/

I should clarify: the advantage of getting the size with a Head request, then doing a Range request, is that you do not have to transfer all the content. You mentioned you have pretty big file resources, so this is going to be the best solution :)

edit: added this code below...

Here is a demo (simplified) of that blog article, but translated into Python. Please note this will not work with all HTTP servers! More comments inline:

```
"""
illustration of how to 'tail' a file using http. this will not work on all
webservers! if you need an http server to test with you can try the
rangehttpserver module:

$ pip install requests
$ pip install rangehttpserver
$ python -m RangeHTTPServer
"""
import requests

TAIL_SIZE = 1024

url = 'http://localhost:8000/lorem-ipsum.txt'
response = requests.head(url)

# not all servers return content-length in head, for some reason
assert 'content-length' in response.headers, 'Content length unknown- out of luck!'

# check the the resource length and construct a request header for that range
full_length = int(response.headers['content-length'])
assert full_length > TAIL_SIZE
headers = {
  'range': 'bytes={}-{}'.format( full_length - TAIL_SIZE, full_length)
}

# Make a get request, with the range header
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
assert 'accept-ranges' in response.headers, 'Accept-ranges response header missing'
assert response.headers['accept-ranges'] == 'bytes'
assert len(response.text) == TAIL_SIZE

# Otherwise you get the entire file
response = requests.get(url)
assert len(response.text) == full_length
```

Comment: that seems to be the right answer, but you should copy/create a working snippet, because link-only answers tend to be downvoted/flagged (ever heard of link-rot).

Comment: BTW I'm not an expert at those things at all, but aren't there websites that do not accept those requests (old sites, like the ones you have to redo all the downloads even if you were at 99% grrrrr :)) ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the pointer! I will make an attempt at translating that example into Python code. (What language is that anyways?) I am pretty sure that HTTP Head request, and the Range header are pretty standard and should be pretty universal. But I am no authority on http servers either.

Comment: I did not flag your answer btw. But someone else might. Post some valid python code and comment back when you are done you ll get my upvote.